# Android: scroll view with titles and text bodies

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to create a simple help screen that looks like the the one shown below. I need to have 8 different titles with smaller sized text bodies below them. I have implemented a scroll view, but how do I vary the font sizes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a similar result in a single TextView by taking advantage of the fact that the TextView has the ability to present a limited set of HTML markup.  For example

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

t.setText(Html.fromHtml("<H1><u><em>Title1</em></u></H1>Details for section 1<H1><u><em>Title2</em></u></H1>Detail for Section 2"));
```

Will render into the TextView with Title1 as a larger font section header, bold and underlined.

This may be satisfactory for your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create different TextViews with different font sizes and styles within a ListView, LinearLayout or TableLayout? Textviews can also support different stylings like HTML.

Comment: I was playing around with those view options for a while. I found that I can achieve something similar by embedding a TableLayout, with a bunch of TextViews, into a ScrollView. However, that combination doesn't look very nice. Thanks for the tips, I'm really lost when it comes to formatting

Comment: Have you trying using a simple Listview?

Comment: Yes, but a ListView doesn't let you scroll and you can't put a ListView within a ScrollView