# How to add a title bar in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, titlebar

i want to add title bar inside the scroll view.
But i can' t do that.

My layout

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

       <ScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorAccent"
  tools:context="com.example.nazir.alrehman.FullRead">

    <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView

        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/a1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="الرَّحۡمٰنُۙ‏ ﴿۱﴾"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
       </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: scroll view with titles and text bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427322/android-scroll-view-with-titles-and-text-bodies)

Comment: @Manmohan_singh he is asking for a title bar not textview

Comment: why do you have two linearlayouts?

Comment: i am saving text vertically in text box.